# Is the Soundbar product category the wrong way to go for a Turntable? A Soundbar is actually for home theater and gaming?

Tags: turntable, streaming, speakers

Because I have little space in the living room, I decided to buy a soundbar (Sony calls it "Vertical Surround Engine").

Now I noticed that the turntable [can not be connected with cable, I have no input for this connection](https://electronics.sony.com/audio/soundbars/all-soundbars/p/htg700). Is this observation correct? I generally prefer cables, also my Desktop is connected with Ethernet cable.

[image]

I have a strong suspicion that sounbars are not for Wi-Fi sound systems, but for gaming and home theater. Is this statement true or only conditionally?

I bought the wrong stuff for my turntable?

Comment: To me, soundbars are what you buy when your TV speakers start buzzing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct--soundbars are generally for home theater or gaming systems. They use modern wireless technology, and are not optimized for analog/wired sound.

It is possible to get a digital converter/broadcaster that will plug into your turntable but then you lose that analog feel.